# Running Visual Studio Load Test Comparisons Against Different Domains

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mstest, load-testing

I have several load tests set up each with a parameterized web test. One for our baseline calculation and another for our comparison calculation.

These 2 sites point to 2 different IIS Sites set up with different sub-domains. 
I switch between these sites using 2 run settings with the domain name passed as a context parameter and run the tests in a batch script as it takes 3 hours to run all of our tests (5 sites * (10 min test run + 5 min warm up) * 2(baseline + comparison) )so I batch them over night as a scheduled task

The problem I am now running into is that when I run our comparison report the baseline shows our baseline URLs but nothing comes up under the comparison side, which is I am assuming is because the domain is slightly different

ie. loadtest.bl.{domain}/page.aspx vs loadtest.{domain}/page.aspx

I am testing page response time to assess that performance improvements implemented in our website are showing effective improvement in page load time

Is there a way to set this up to ignore the domain name in the comparison or is there another option with out having to set the url the same for all tests and change the IP binding between test runs for baseline and comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the output format of the test results file is XML, after the first test, you could run a powershell script  that changes the result URL to be the same as the URL in the second test. When you run the baseline, the result files should contain the same URL.

Comment: we actually did something similar to this but using HOSTS entry and updating the hosts file between sequential runs as these were targeting in internal test server environment this was not a deal